# Terminal error using Test First Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, terminal, test-first

I'm just starting Test First Ruby & I'm having trouble running rakes to start solving problems.

I think it's either my version of RSpec or my version of Ruby that's causing the error.

Here's the error,

```
AT MacBook-Pro:01_temperature AT$ rake
(in /Users/AT/Desktop/learn_ruby)
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- temperature (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/AT/Desktop/learn_ruby/01_temperature/temperature_spec.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/AT/Desktop/learn_ruby/01_temperature/temperature_spec.rb -I/Users/AT/Desktop/learn_ruby/01_temperature -I/Users/AT/Desktop/learn_ruby/01_temperature/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
```

I had a similar problem a few minutes ago but fixed by uninstalling RSpec v-3, and installing v-2.14.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file `temperature_spec` is requiring what I presume is the source for the class under test, `temperature` - but the RSpec loader is not able to resolve the path for this file.

It would be helpful for you to post both the source of your rspec file and your class under test.